# Configure Artifactory to work with external MSSQL server error

Tags: sql, linux, yaml, artifactory

I try to install Artifactory 7.11 on linux instance.

Detiles:
Cloud: AWS
OS: amazon linux

If i start the service with the default configuration everything work properly.

But if i uncomment the database section in the system.yaml file to work with SQL server i got an error that the "system.yaml validation failed" at node .shared.database.

Note that the connection details like user,password are checked and worked.
Additionally - the sql port(1433) port is already opened.

As you can see that the connection to the DB succeeded:

[image: error]

**Default configuration file looks like this:**

[image: Default configuration( with local filesystem storage)]

**Configuration file with connection to the DB**

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what can be the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey David, Can you lint the system.yaml? Is that valid yaml? Also the Warning you indicate should not stop the service, does the service start up in the end?

Comment: @PrasannaRaghavendra - 1. the yaml file is actually a copy of system-basic.template.yaml.  2. regarding the service status - the services looks that are not running(except frontend that is running) although that  they still have PID.  3. if i try access the service from browser i get error 404

Comment: Hey David, understood - when you edited, if there is a tab or anything that came in inadvertently - you could see this. We will check the basic template as well.

Comment: David, can you also check artifactory-service.log to see what it says?

Comment: 2020-12-31T14:13:53.261Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [3ee136d5c4e7e5d2] [tifactoryHomeConfigListener:62] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Failed initializing Home. Caught exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader

Comment: @PrasannaRaghavendra  The JFROG_HOME is defined to /jforg.  Maybee its related to the driver?

Comment: Have you followed these steps to set up your MSSQL Database and the SQL driver? https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Microsoft+SQL+Server It indeed looks like a driver issue.

Comment: JFROG_HOME should be the extracted directory if it is a linux archive installation.

Comment: yes, i've worked following this guide... regarding JFROG_HOME i've extracted the installation in /jfrog so i think that the JFROG_HOME point to the right path..

Comment: Hey David, Can you check in the log if the driver was bootstrapped - there should be a log entry to say it was copied over in artifactory-service.log. Hoping the service had permission to copy over

Comment: @PrasannaRaghavendra - i don't see in the log file line that say that the driver has copied to anywhere....

Comment: BTW now i see this line : 2020-12-31T14:17:29.633Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [b7bf5ac5cbac658f] [tifactoryHomeConfigListener:70] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Resolved Home: '/jfrog/artifactory

Comment: Can you check if the driver is in this path `/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/lib` and confirm if you added it in `/jfrog/artifactory/var/bootstrap/artifactory/tomcat/lib`

Comment: @PrasannaRaghavendra - i see the driver in /jfrog/artifactory/var/bootstrap/artifactory/tomcat/lib but not in /jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/lib.   Where is the refernce that it should be in the secund path?

Comment: The start should take care of it - the drivers are named with prefix `jf_` in the target folder - you do not see it there? Can you check the permission on the driver, does artifactory user has permissions to read the driver? I assume you did a restart after copying the file to bootstrap folder?

Comment: @PrasannaRaghavendra - you are right.. after i start the service i see few jar files like jf_mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.jar   jf_mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12-shaded.ja. jf_mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre11-shaded.jar. jf_mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre11.jarmeans that the driver already copied to the target path..      Anyway i've changed permission to all /jfrog/artifactory/var folder to 777 and still not work

Comment: Can you pls now see the error you are getting in the service log - if the drivers are there, it should have found them, should be able to load.

Answer (score 2):

After a long examination I finally understood the main reason...

1. default the IPv6 is configured, so i've disable the ip section in the system.yaml and put the IPv4 server ip
2. multiple sql drivers was in the folder so i've deleted all of them except the v11.jar

Thanks @Prasanna for your help!